# angular ng-repeat does not reverse the order of elements when $index is reversed

Tags: angularjs

I have written the following code to print the list in descending order in terms of index position.

```
 <div class="item-layout" ng-repeat="item in selectedMenueItems track by $index | orderBy : '-$index'">
</div>
```

But somehow, it is only printing the data in ascending order only in terms of index. Is there anything missing here?

Comment: it won't work because angular doesn't define a property named `'-$index'`

Comment: @svarog what should I modify to make it work?

Comment: just as @Korte suggested, if his solution doesn't work for you, post more of your code, maybe there's a bug somewhere or an error..

Answer (score 3):

You got to use the `reverse` parameter in `orderBy` filter here.

e.g.

```
<div ng-controller="AppController as app">
  <div ng-repeat="item in app.items  | orderBy:'$index':true track by $index ">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/t91wf4se/8/)

Answer (score 1):

change this line `orderBy : '-$index'` to `orderBy : '$index' : true` to get the desired result.

Refer the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy for more better understanding.